# How to store a 5 gallon bucket of pickle slices?

Tags: refrigerator, pickles

A family member just gave us a 5 gallon bucket of kosher hamburger dill slices (for frying).  I moved the shelves and shifted everything around, and found room for it. The shelves are tempered glass, so I placed it on the bottom shelf, above the vegetable drawers. If the shelf doesn't break, then this will work, for now. The bucket says to keep refrigerated. Any ideas on other options for how to store it?

Answer (score 3):

I'd transfer to pint mason jars and store in the refrigerator -- at least until I figured out what to do next.

Comment: I found room for it, for now. I think splitting it into mason jars would take up more space. I didn't think the fridge was big enough for a five gallon bucket, but somehow it fit.

Answer (score 2):

Given the rectangular shape of a refrigerator, I'd transfer into rectangular, stackable, smaller containers that can lurk at the back of many shelves, rather than one big hulking bucket on the bottom shelf. This also limits contamination as you open the container to get some to eat, makes it easier to decide to get some to eat, and allows the fridge space used to shrink as you use up each container.

I'd also suggest eating (frying? pickles? OK...?) a bunch. Have a fried pickle themed new years eve party.

As far as I know you can't can them for room temperature storage without pretty much ruining their essential difference from pickles that come that way - as I understand it, kosher dills are naturally fermented and thus always kept under refrigeration.

Alternatively, find an additional fridge (perhaps one with wire shelves) and make it the *pickle fridge* ;-) it could live somewhere out of the way (like the basement) and you'd take your smaller container from the kitchen fridge down when it ran out to refill from the big bucket. But this may be a bit overkill unless this will be a recurring bucket of pickles.

Comment: Battered, fried pickles are a common appetizer in my area.